# Excluding row in database with != in PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to exclude certain rows with a PDO query but it is not returning the right value and I'm not seeing my error maybe some of you can help me.

This is the first query that works.

```
$objGetRecievedChat = $objDatabaseMessages->prepare('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE recieverid = :recieverid GROUP BY chatid');
```

Now I want to exclude the `chatid`'s that I get from this query.

```
foreach ($getRecievedChatFtch as $chatid) {
 echo $chatid['chatid'] . '<BR>';
}
```

When I echo the above I get the next result:

```
20920
81586
```

Wich is correct I want to exclude those two values so I execute the next query:

```
  $objGetSendChat = $objDatabaseMessages->prepare('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE ownerid = :ownerid AND chatid != :chatid GROUP BY chatid');

foreach ($getSendChat as $key ) {
 echo $key['chatid'] . '<BR>';
}
```

But when I echo the above I get the next values

```
44495
20920
44495
```

this value `44495` is correct although I only need it once (that is why I `GROUP BY chatid`) But the value `20920` is one of the values I need to exclude.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Whole code:

```
//Voor de berichten die je hebt ontvangen.
$objGetRecievedChat = $objDatabaseMessages->prepare('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE recieverid = :recieverid GROUP BY chatid');
$objGetRecievedChat->bindParam('recieverid', $member_id);
$objGetRecievedChat->execute();

$getRecievedChatFtch = $objGetRecievedChat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//Dit is voor verzonden berichten.
foreach ($getRecievedChatFtch as $chatid) {
  echo $chatid['chatid'] . '<BR>';

  $objGetSendChat = $objDatabaseMessages->prepare('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE ownerid = :ownerid AND chatid NOT IN(:chatid) GROUP BY chatid');
  $objGetSendChat->bindParam('ownerid', $member_id);
  $objGetSendChat->bindParam('chatid', $chatid['chatid']);

  $objGetSendChat->execute();
  $getSendChat = $objGetSendChat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  foreach ($getSendChat as $key) {
    echo $key['chatid'] . '<BR>';
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't exclude with PD, PDO doesn't matter here. You just exclude with the query itself. If you have an array of data you can use `WHERE chatid NOT IN(:chatid)`

Comment: If you do a `GROUP BY chatid` you can't get the same chatid echoed twice.  I feel like you're not sharing the entire story.

Comment: I don't get it, there is an array with 2 elements you want to exclude and your query has only 1 `chatid != :chatid `. How are you binding your variables? And you probably need `chatid NOT IN (.., ..)`.

Comment: I'm using bindParam to bind variables.

Answer (score 1):

You're making it wrong: in your foreach loop, you retrieve ALL rows BUT the current one. You must put the query out of the `foreach` and use a `WHERE IN`

```
//Voor de berichten die je hebt ontvangen.
$objGetRecievedChat = $objDatabaseMessages->prepare('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE recieverid = :recieverid GROUP BY chatid');
$objGetRecievedChat->bindParam('recieverid', $member_id);
$objGetRecievedChat->execute();

$getRecievedChatFtch = $objGetRecievedChat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//Dit is voor verzonden berichten.
$chatids = array();
foreach ($getRecievedChatFtch as $chatid) {
  echo $chatid['chatid'] . '<BR>';
  $chatids = $chatid['chatid'];
}

$placeholders = implode(',', array_fill('?', count($chatids)));
$objGetSendChat = $objDatabaseMessages->prepare('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE ownerid = ? AND chatid NOT IN(' . $placeholders . ') GROUP BY chatid');

$objGetSendChat->execute(array_merge(array($ownerid, $chatids)));
$getSendChat = $objGetSendChat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($getSendChat as $key) {
  echo $key['chatid'] . '<BR>';
}
```

More or less (because I dislike using `WHERE IN` with prepared statement. You usually can avoid them with `JOIN`.

---

`$objGetSendChat = ...`

While you use `$getSendChat` in the `foreach`.

So I feel we're missing some code here, that contains the error.

Plus, you do a `GROUP BY chatid` and you get `44495` twice in the result, so the result *cannot* be the query's one.

Comment: I'm just doing a fetchall.

Comment: $getSendChat = $objGetSendChat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: Having twice the same value from a `GROUP BY` column means the result is not the one from the query, so you should edit your question and show the whole code.

Comment: Updated my original comment.

Comment: Now that's better. Everytime you fire your query in the `foreach`, you'll get ALL rows BUT the current one, hence your results.

Answer (score 1):

Change query to catid NOT IN (xxxx,xxxx).

Comment: Still gives the same results as before.